# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Failed to link module-info (Module "javax.json.api" version 1.1.2 from local module loader @307db34d

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, jbpm

I am running jbpm (version jbpm-server-7.17.0.Final-dist) with OpenJdk 1.8. 
 Wildfly server is getting started fine and I am able to create a sample process with single human node and able to execute it.

Problem starts when I am trying to add lombok Slf4j, logback classic, jackson data bind libraries to achieve logging using logback in the human task. After adding the above dependencies and on click of build, following error is being thrown

```
16:41:57,480 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (default task-8) Failed to define class module-info in Module "javax.json.api" version 1.1.2 from local module loader @307db34d (finder: local module finder @3f3f8e92 (roots: D:\jBPM\jbpm-server-7.17.0.Final-dist\modules,D:\jBPM\jbpm-server-7.17.0.Final-dist\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Failed to link module-info (Module "javax.json.api" version 1.1.2 from local module loader @307db34d (finder: local module finder @3f3f8e92 (roots: D:\jBPM\jbpm-server-7.17.0.Final-dist\modules,D:\jBPM\jbpm-server-7.17.0.Final-dist\modules\system\layers\base))): JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=module-info, offset=6
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
```

I have searched the error "JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=module-info, offset=6" and found it is because of javac and java version mismatch while compiling and executing a specific class respectively.

If I switch to java 9 to run the jbpm server, I start getting another error for the same class

```
15:00:50,312 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (default task-3) Failed to define class module-info in Module "javax.json.api" version 1.1.2 from local module loader @4f0100a7 (finder: local module finder @3cdf2c61 (roots: D:\jBPM\jbpm-server-7.22.0.Final-dist\modules,D:\jBPM\jbpm-server-7.22.0.Final-dist\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link module-info (Module "javax.json.api" version 1.1.2 from local module loader @4f0100a7 (finder: local module finder @3cdf2c61 (roots: D:\jBPM\jbpm-server-7.22.0.Final-dist\modules,D:\jBPM\jbpm-server-7.22.0.Final-dist\modules\system\layers\base))): module-info is not a class because access_flag ACC_MODULE is set
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007)
```

Following are the dependencies I am trying to add to the jbpm project i have created

```
 <dependencies>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
             <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
             <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
              <version>6.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

is there is way to get rid of this error? Thank you for your help in advance. Would be nice if I would be able to run jbpm server with open jdk 1.8. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have made some progress. Download https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonp/releases 1.1.4 and compile with 1.8. Then replace version 1.1.6 they use in your installation(Mine is C:\Program Files\jBPM\modules\system\layers\base\javax\json api and bind) jbpm. You need also to modify module.xml change 1.9 to 1.8 and 1.1.6 to 1.1.4. This will remove that warn. Now you will get Warn that jakarta.json.bind-api 1.02 is compiled with 1.9, which is. You need to find https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonb-api/releases and build with 1.8 and then replace in "bind" folder and modify module.xml....